# What is the best approach to call web service from azure sql?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlclr

What is the best approach to call web service from azure sql(from stored procedure)?
I understand that azure sql doesn't support CLR assemblies(SQLCLR).

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It is normal for Services to access db's not the other way round. Try building a service which can access the DB and the web service and combine the results.

Comment: We have built very complex logic in SP's, which takes quite some time to re-write and performance aspect is the one thing to consider.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot access external resources (network, file system, registry, etc) from Azure SQL Database. Neither SQLCLR nor OLE Automation stored procedures (i.e. `sp_OA*`) are available on that platform. Even during the year-and-a-half that Azure SQL Database supported SQLCLR (late 2014 through mid-April 2016), it was `SAFE` Assemblies only, and those can not do external operations.

Your only option is to handle this outside of Azure SQL Database, or use an Azure VM with SQL Server loaded on it (Express Edition is free, so you would only pay for the Azure VM itself, which might be a cost-effective option).