# How to Call Webservice/CLR functions from Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

Im using SQL Server 2016. My DB contains Web service calls and .net Assemblies incorporated (CLR Functions). 
I'm planning to move my DB to Azure SQL. Is it possible to call Webservices/CLR functions from Azure SQL? I see **[this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708820/what-is-the-best-approach-to-call-web-service-from-azure-sql)** says its not possible. Is there any update/other way around?

How does Cosmos DB support support w.r.to this scenario? Please Suggest

Comment: Doing so on an on-premise database is a *very serious* design failure. Those calls block transaction for a long time and consume memory that would be used for buffering instead. Doing so on Azure SQL would be much worse, which is why it's not allowed. Calling web services is the job of client applications and ETL scripts, not SQLCLR functions

Comment: The *correct* way to call web services is to use SSIS or a custom ETL script. Migrating SSIS packages to Azure [is already supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I would really suggest moving this kind of logic out of database. You'll make your life easier by letting database be just a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Azure does not support CLR in-database.  However, SQL Azure Managed Instance does.  So, please look into that option.

Your other possible approach is to consider what logic exists in CLR and see if you can move to T-SQL equivalents.  Since CLR was added, we now have batch mode processing (Columnstore) as well as in-memory tables/natively compiled stored procedures.  Both options are pretty fast alternatives that may solve your problem.  In-memory tables are supported on SQL Azure with >= 1 core due to associated memory requirements.  Columnstore works on S3 and above in Standard and on Premium/V-core options.

Comment: Moving a bad desing to the cloud won't make it a better design. It will cost a lot more though

Comment: Merely using extensibility mechanisms such as CLR does not make a database design bad.   I do agree that there's often opportunity for poorly-designed database applications to re-think their design to improve their performance/reduce the cost to run in a hosting environment such as a public cloud

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use CLR functions on Azure SQL Database but you can use CLR functions on an Azure Managed Instance with some restrictions. Managed Instance cannot access file shares and Windows folders, so the following constraints apply:

- Only CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM BINARY is supported.
- CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM FILE is not supported.
- ALTER ASSEMBLY cannot reference files.

To learn about Azure Managed Instances, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance) documentation.